# Corrupt XML layout when Changing mobile language

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

I have a listview that gets its data from firebase and works fine. the problem I have is whenever I change mobile language that listview gets a weird design, but I only change mobile language and nothing else.
here is my list item xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/all_docs_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_doctor"
        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/all_docs_image"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/all_docs_name"
            android:fontFamily="@font/cairo_semibold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            tools:text="Dr. Ahmad" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/all_docs_speciality"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/cairo"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            tools:text="Cardiac" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/all_availability_green_dot_imageView"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/availability_green_dot" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I wanted to look like this, which it does,[image: all doctors list View]

but it looks like this when I change mobile language to Arabic
[image]

Comment: You have at least one absolute direction in your layout, on the `<LinearLayout>`: `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/all_docs_image"`. You want `layout_toEndOf` instead. Also make sure that you're using relative directions everywhere else, too. That's the only one I saw, though.

Comment: @MikeM. thx a lot, I usually only use start and end, but it seems that it passed me this time